# Navigation bar in (almost) every component

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I want to have a side navigation and a top navigation on top of (almost) every page component. How can I do that in an efficient way? Basically, I don't want to include the navigation bar inside every component's HTML file, and I can't put it directly inside the app.component.html because I don't want it on every page component. Is there some solution like including it as a provider, or by somehow including it using a decorator?

Comment: One solution is to make a container component that includes the common components. That component then wraps other components where you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use part of the path to determine which 'template' to show. Let's say you create two templates, one with and one without the nav bar.

Now create two modules in which you also define a router module.
You can now easily define which 'template' to use for a specific route

`http://your.site/bananas` <- uses template one
`http://your.site/apples` <- uses template two

You can do this by defining your routes like so:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'bananas',
        component: DesiredTemplateComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: ComponentToShowForThisPage }
        ]
    }
];
```

And for your other module

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'apples',
        component: DifferentTemplateComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', component: ComponentToShowForThisPage }
        ]
    }
];
```